# How to add a costum Component on Fxml?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a costum Button that i made, however how can i use it in the fxml file?
I tried to create a normal Button and on the controller do something like "@FXML
    private CrazyButton button;" which causes the application to crash.

So lets whit the example of the CrazyButton, how can i add a costumComponent in the fxml file?

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class CrazyButton extends Button {

    public CrazyButton(){
        setText("Crazy");
    }
}
```

This my fxml file:

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
      fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
       <!--I Wanted my costum button to be here-->
   </children>
</Pane>
```

So there i can use it on own my controller:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private CrazyButton button;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Same way you do with anything else: `<CrazyButton fx:id="button"/>`. Make sure you add the import, using whatever package name you have for the class.

Comment: But how i import him? Crazybutton is just a class.

Comment: Presumably you put the class in a package, so just import it in exactly the same way you import the library classes: `<?import my.package.CrazyButton ?>`.

Comment: So u are saying is, if i put the CostumButton in a package.  I can then import the package on the top of the fxml and use  <CostumButton> as a tag?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing special about the library classes over classes you create or a third party creates. They all work the same way in FXML (just as they all work the same way in Java).

Comment: I will give it a try, once i get to my pc. Thanks James_D once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaFX library classes are not "privileged" in any sense with respect to FXML; the `FXMLLoader` instantiates all classes the same way. You just need to make sure your custom class is in a package (it is extremely bad practice to use the "default package" anyway), and then import it in the FXML and use it exactly the same way you do any other class. If your class is in a package `my.package` this looks like

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane ?>
<?import my.package.CrazyButton ?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
      fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
       <CrazyButton fx:id="button" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```